# How to remove shipping address from Woocommerce myaccount page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, account

I created the custom myaccount page for Woocommerce that you can see in the screenshot below. Now I would like to know how I can remove the Shipping Address (Verzendadres in Dutch) section. I've tried overwriting the myaccount.php files on the server but can't get this to work. I am using this in combination with the Astra theme for Wordpress.

[image: Woocommerce myaccount page]

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `woocommerce_my_account_get_addresses` filter hook to hide shipping address in My account "Addresses" section, this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_get_addresses', 'filter_wc_my_account_get_addresses', 10, 2 ); 
function filter_wc_my_account_get_addresses( $adresses, $customer_id ) { 
    if( isset($adresses['shipping']) ) {
        unset($adresses['shipping']);
    }
    return $adresses; 
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble changing the theme directly in wordpress, try going into your customizer through (appearance -> customize) in the administrator dashboard, then selecting "Additional Css", then select the shipping form through css and add

```
display: none;
```

to the shipping field